How to handle dependencies dynamically in a Java microservice architecture without restarting the service?
I’m building a microservice architecture for an e-library system, where each service depends on configurations (like database connection strings or third-party API keys) that can change dynamically. I want to update these dependencies without restarting the service.
Current Approach:
I’m using a configuration server (e.g., Spring Cloud Config) to fetch configuration values at startup.
Dependencies are initialized during the application startup, making them static during the application's lifecycle.
However, if a dependency changes (e.g., a database migration or an API key rotation), the service requires a restart to apply the updated configuration, which isn’t ideal in a production environment.
What I’m Looking For:
How can I design the application to dynamically reload or refresh these dependencies at runtime?
Are there libraries or frameworks in Java that can help implement this pattern effectively?
How can I ensure consistency and avoid race conditions when dependencies are updated while the service is handling requests?
What I’ve Tried:
Implemented a custom configuration watcher that listens for changes from the configuration server and updates a shared object.
Example code:
java
public class ConfigWatcher {  
    private volatile DatabaseConfig databaseConfig;  
    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000) // Poll every 10 seconds  
    public void refreshConfig() {  
        this.databaseConfig = configServer.fetchDatabaseConfig();  
    }  
    
    public DatabaseConfig getDatabaseConfig() {  
        return databaseConfig;  
    }  
}  

While this works for simple configurations, it becomes problematic for more complex dependencies like database connection pools, which don’t support "hot-swapping."
Questions:
How can I handle more complex dependencies like connection pools or HTTP clients dynamically?
Are there better design patterns or frameworks for achieving dynamic dependency updates in Java microservices?
How can I test such systems for consistency during runtime updates?
Any guidance, code examples, or design insights would be greatly appreciated!
I tried initializing the book object, but I’m not sure where to do it correctly.

You wrote (in your question): Are there libraries or frameworks in Java that can help implement this pattern effectively? For your information, questions asking for third-party tool recommendations are considered off-topic.

I believe that you can use Spring cloud config project. Which is centerlized configuration system that will handle and store all neccessary configuration for your microservices.
Then, All microservices interconnected into config server and use RefreshScope annotation. For example basic tutorial link attached here
